# How can find the lowest value of a calculation based on several variables?

Tags: loops, coldfusion, random, recursion, artificial-intelligence

Caveat: I'm using ColdFusion, but I feel this is could cover a broad range of languages, as this is more of a programming question, not just a ColdFusion question.

Ok, I have been tasked with implementing code to apply promotions to items in a shopping cart. Basically, there can be any number of promotions for any number of items - i.e. "Buy 2 of item 'ABC', get 1 of item 'ABC' 50% off". However, there can also be "buy **3** of item 'ABC', get 1 of item 'ABC' free". Or even "buy 2 of item 'ABC', get 1 of item 'XYZ' 50% off".

So, imagine there are more promotions running like this across a broad range of products.

Now, I need to run through every scenario possible to apply the promotion (or promotionS) that give the customer the best possible value (the lowest sub-total).

However, I cannot figure out how to write the code that will run through EVERY possible scenario. I am able to narrow the number of promotions that eligible, by filtering out those that do not apply to the items in the cart. Obviously, I also know the number of eligible items in the cart.

So, let's say I have 5 items in my cart, and 3 of those items have eligible promotions (such as those above). 1 item has 3 possible promotions, another has 4 possible promotions, another has 2 possible promotions. My first thought is, loop through each possible promotion, and within that loop, loop though each possible order of eligible items:

1-2-3
1-3-2
2-1-3
2-3-1
3-1-2
3-2-1

...and apply the promotions each time, saving the combination that produces the lowest sub-total.

Will this work? Is it overkill? Does anyone have a better suggestion?

Any code samples would be greatly appreciated. Although I'm programming this in ColdFusion, I can read/understand other languages just fine.

Thank you.

Comment: What are you supposed to do if two promos apply to one product? Actually apply both, or drop the one that costs the seller more?

Comment: I wonder if this isn't better suited to programmers.so. In many cases I think you can simply store a value for each promotion that only gets updated when the price for an item changes. Then you can iterate through the cart and eliminate items as you apply the highest absolute promotion values first.

Comment: to be honest in real world its allways the biggest sell goes for biggest promo, just try the biggest promo -> if its ok try again if not go to smaller etc.

Comment: +1 for an interesting question. Also added artificial-intelligence tag because I suspect this problem may be NP complete.

Comment: See this question as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426173/what-is-the-algorithm-to-determine-the-best-way-to-distribute-these-coupons

Answer (score 3):

Rather then looping through the items and look for combinations, you can loop through the promotions and pattern match with shopping cart, maybe easier?

Or maybe you can assign priority to the promotions, if one is always superior then the other?  So if one is applied, you can skip all promotions with lower priority?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like a search problem. Well, every problem is a search problem. I would start with a simple depth-first search since that uses up little memory.

Below is some pseudo code for the depth-first search.

```
def bestSetOfPromotions(cart, promotions, applied-promotions):
    if (len(promotions) == 0):     #no more choices
        return applied-promotions
    best-set = [] #best set of promotions found so far, the empty set.
    for next-promotion in promotions:
        if canApply(next-promotion, cart, applied-promotions):
            best = bestSetOfPromotions(cart, promotions.remove(next-promotion), applied-promotions.push(next-promotion))
            if (costOf(cart, best) < costOf(cart,best-set)):
               best-set = best
    return best-set

#we call it as such:
bestSetOfPromotions(cart, allThePromotions, [])
```

The code above assumes that a promotion can only be applied once. Changing to allow multiple applications of the same promotion should be simple.

The code checks all possible orderings of all legal (canApply) promotions and finds the one that gives the lowest cost to the given 'cart'. This will take O(2^len(promotions)).

If this search takes too long I would recommend modifying it to a branch-and-bound search and ordering the promotions from biggest to smallest.

Comment: +1 interesting approach - it appears this assumes you can completely explore every possibility and then choose the lowest cost? Any scaling concerns?

Comment: @organgepips Branch and bound scales out horribly (but still a lot better than brute force), but as long as he's below 10-20 items (or more?) in his cart, he should be safe: he 'll see which item hits the cap: the execution time will go from milliseconds to hours for just 1 more item. But branch and bound is one of the best exact algorithms. Reality is, if this is indeed NP Complete, it's not possible today to combine scaling out and being exact.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Henry's answer, I think the solution depends on the how promotions are handled. This is probably solvable optimally every time if:

1. there's no limit to the number of promotions of a given type (e.g. buy one get one) that can be applied to an order
2. the number of items that a given promotion applies to is finite (no buy one full price and get as many as you want half off) and the greater the number the lower the per unit cost
3. a promotion only applies to one "type" of item and an item is only of one type (e.g. books).

The point in #2 is used to determine "priority" such that an algorithm would group items by type and number of that type and iterate through these groups to find promotion(s) that apply.

Now if what's noted above is **untrue** I think you are now dealing with a problem where it's not possible to assert how long it would take to arrive at the "best" solution absent finding every other solution as well. Now if the number of items is small this may be feasible to find every possibility and choose the lowest cost, but I imagine that the number of possibilities grows exponentially based on number of items and number possible promotions. I would call this an [NP complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete) problem.

Instead, you want an algorithm that produces "good" solutions in a reasonable amount of time. If that's true I think an approach called [simulated annealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) is applicable: basically an algorithm that's iterated through some arbitrary number of times (you'll need to test to find a value that's acceptable in terms of performance). The algorithm is seeded randomly with inputs, in this case applicable promotions. The algorithm returns total cost. Each iteration changes the algorithm's input - where part of the overall algorithm is  finding two iterations that produced a "good" result and taking a combination of their inputs for a another iteration.